# Next-i18next serverSideTranslations initialI18nStore missing locales

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-i18next, next-i18next

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { locale } = context;
  const translations = await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"]);

  console.log(translations._nextI18Next.initialI18nStore)
}
```

is showing only the ones from the current locale and default locale if it is the case.

this is my `next-18next.config.js` file:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: "de",
    locales: ["de", "en", "fr", "it"],
  },
  localePath: path.resolve("./src/locales"),
};
```

and my `locales` look something like this:

[image]

I would like to find in the `initialI18nStore` all the locales defined by me in the config. Why it isn't showing all of them?

Comment: In my case I'm trying to access the locales from the hook: `const { i18n } = useTranslation(); console.log(i18n.languages);` and indeed the same issue with the default locale. However when I use another locale then all the locales are displayed. There must be some bug.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `locales` array containing all supported locales from the `context` object in `getStaticProps`.

```js
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { locale, locales } = context;
  const translations = await serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"]);

  console.log(locales); // Will log `['de', 'en', 'fr', 'it']`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. I used to get all locales translations strings using `serverSideTranslations(locale, ["common"])` and suddenly I started to receiving only current locale's translations and default. I made a workaround to get all translations:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { locales } = context;

  for (const locale of locales) {
    const currentLocaleTranslation = await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common']);

    // do something with your translations
  }
}
```